# Is there a way to classify all finite groups $G$, such that $\pi(G) := \Pi_{H \triangleleft G} |H| = |G|^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, products

Is there a way to classify all finite groups $G$, such that $\pi(G) := \Pi_{H \triangleleft G} |H| = |G|^2$?

For abelian groups this problem is quite simple. All such abelian groups are exactly $C_{p^3}$ and $C_{pq}$ for any primes $p$ and $q$:

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are abelian groups of coprime order. Then if $P \times Q$ satisfies that condition, then $\pi(P)|Q|^2 \leq \pi(P \times Q) = |P \times Q|^2 = |P|^2|Q|^2$ and thus  $\pi(P) \leq |P|^2$.

So, to solve the problem we need to obtain the classification of all finite abelian $P$-groups, satisfying the condition $\pi(P) \leq |P|^2$.

Suppose, a finite abelian $p$-group $P$ is a direct product of $n$ cyclic groups. Then it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $C_p^n$. So $\pi(P) \geq \pi(C_p^n) = \Pi_{k = 0}^n (p^k)^{C_n^k} = p^{\Sigma_{k = 0}^n kC_n^k} = p^{n2^{n-1}} > |P|^2$ for any $n > 1$. So $P$ has to be cyclic.

For cyclic $p$-groups $P$ we can see $\pi({C_{p^n}}) = p^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$. So, the group satisfies our condition iff $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \leq 2n$ which is exactly, when $n \leq 3$.

Now one can also see that $\pi(C_{p^2q}) = p^6q^3 \geq |\pi(C_{p^2q})|^2$ and $\pi(C_{pqr}) = (pqr)^3 \geq |\pi(C_{pqr})|^2$ for any prime $p$, $q$ and $r$. So, only possible examples are of one of the following forms: $C_{p^3}$, $C_{p^2}$, $C_{p}$, $E$, $C_{pq}$. And one can via manual checking see, that only $C_{p^3}$ and $C_{pq}$ do actually satisfy that condition.

However, I do not know, what to do there in non-abelian case.

Comment: The non-abelian simple case is simple.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes, it is. No simple group satisfies this condition, as $\pi(G) = |G|$ for any simple group $G$.

Comment: That's what I meant with simple. So in this case you do know, what to do in the non-abelian case. Did you try some non-abelian groups of low order? One could also try the quasisimple groups, i.e.,  perfect groups whose inner automorphism group is simple.

Comment: The smallest nonabelian example is $A_5\times C_2$. More generally, if $R$ and $S$ are two simple groups not both isomorphic to $C_p$, then $R\times S$ will be an example.

Comment: Suppose $G$ has at least two maximal normal subgroups $N$ and $M$.Note that $NM=G$ so $|G|=|N|M|/|N\cap M|$. If $N\cap M> 1$, then all these normal subgroups already give something bigger than $|G|^2$. So we have that $G$ is a direct product of two normal subgroups. Note that the bound is already tight, so they must be simple, and they cannot be both isomorphic to a particular $C_p$, and we get the examples above.

Comment: The remaining case is when $G$ has a unique maximal normal subgroup, say $N$. Note that $G/N$ must be simple. If $G/N$ is cyclic of order $p$, then there is just one more normal subgroup, say $M$, and it has order $p$. Note that $M\leq N$ and $M/N$ is simple. If $|M/N|$ is abelian, it must have order $p$ (and we get the $C_{p^3}$ example), otherwise we get an extra normal subgroup. So we can assume $M/N$ is nonabelian simple. It's easy to see that in this case $N$ is quasisimple, with center of order $p$, and $|G:N|=p$. Note that such examples do arise, such as $2.S_5^+$ and $2.S_5^-$.

Comment: The last remaining case would be when $G$ has a unique maximal normal subgroup $N$, and $G/N$ is non-abelian simple. I'm not sure if this case can arise.